# ChromeCast SDK Album Art

Tags: android, chromecast

Using the default ChromeCast RemoteMediaPlayer class and the default receiver, how do you add album art to the page?  I have tried looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaMetadata.html, but there does not appear to be a entry for album art.  There is a bug place holder on the screen though, so I assume it is supported somehow.  I looked at https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample/blob/master/player.js, and there appears to be a case where it tries to get the art work with `ar artwork = sampleplayer.getValue_(event.data, ['media', 'metadata', 'images', 0, 'url']);`, but I don't see any way to actually fill that out from the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MediaMetadata](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaMetadata.html) hold reference to images and has an [addImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaMetadata.html#addImage%28com.google.android.gms.common.images.WebImage%29) method. That is where you have to keep the info about your images, including album art (you can add as many references as you want, possibly different aspect ratios, resolutions, etc)

Comment: Well I feel stupid for not having seen that considering how long I spent looking at the documentation.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi I have a similiar problem but with the chrome api. It just won't work. Any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823031/chromecast-chrome-api-how-to-set-change-album-art

Comment: @AliNaddaf its dont works properly sometimes it loads upper half of the image when image is of high quality

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot make it work, you could use this javascript library:
https://github.com/fenny/castjs

```
var device = new Castjs();
device.on('available', () => {
  device.cast('https://fenny.github.io/Castjs/demo/poster.jpg', {
      poster:      'https://fenny.github.io/Castjs/demo/poster.jpg',
      title:       'Sintel',
      description: 'Third Open Movie by Blender Foundation',
      subtitles: [{
        active: true,
        label:  'English',
        source: 'https://fenny.github.io/Castjs/demo/english.vtt'
      }, {
        label:  'Spanish',
        source: 'https://fenny.github.io/Castjs/demo/spanish.vtt'
      }],
      muted:  false,
      paused: false
    })
  });
});
```

Notice the "poster" value, good luck.