# Can I change album art on a chromecast styled media receiver without using RemoteMediaPlayer.load?

Tags: android, chromecast

After finding out that the Cordova plugin I use to work with Chromecast doesn't send the MediaInfo.Metadata I provide (see [How to set/change album art?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823031/how-to-set-change-album-art)), I've decided to implement it myself. But this brings me to the following question:

Can I **change** the album art image **after** I loaded the media using `RemoteMediaPlayer.load()`?

The thing is that I'm using the chromecast to play a radio stream, so it would be nice if I could change the 'now playing' info without reloading the entire stream. I only want to set the title and image(s).

This is, of course, possible when I build my own Custom Receiver app but I hope that the default Styled Media Receiver already provides some method for this.

I think I would need to use `sendMessage()`, and [the Chromecast Developer site does mention sending messages and images](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/messages), but it only says that 'media messages' have a predefined namespace (`urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media`) and then nothing. It says images have three properties (url, width, height) but not what the syntax of the message should be.

So can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styled or default receiver use the current media's metadata to show an album art, so you cannot change the album art without loading a new media.If you want to do that, you need to write your own custom receiver and use a custom namespace to send messages; since that will be a custom namespace, you can decide what the content for the textual payload should be; SDK doesn't enforce one vs the other.

Comment: Thanks that is a quick and solid answer. Hmm. So can I find the code for the Styled Media Receiver somewhere? Because I think I can get away with adding one single message listener to it :D

Comment: The source for Styled/Default receivers is not open. You can grab this sample that should be adequate for what you want, as a staring point: https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample

Comment: Thanks, already found that one. Again thanks for replying so quickly

Comment: PS: Is there a place where I can leave a feature request for this?

Comment: You can use our public SDK issue tracker to file a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list